# How do I edit javascript files while debugging web-api in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, gulp

Yesterday I was compile and debug my visual studio project: Which is a combination of javascript and web-api code. I was able to edit the javascript files while the web-api debugger was running.

Unfortunately, I had to wipe out the project and downloaded it again from source. Today I can no longer edit javascript files while the project is debugging. Furthermore, TaskRunner Explorer used to be visible while I was debugging (it would compile html/javascript/etc as I made changes) now TaskRunner explorer is only visible/active when I am not debugging the Visual Studio code.

I've done searches in Google and Stackoverflow to no result. Does anyone know how to configure Visual Studio to go back to the way things used to be for me?
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: do you want _VS_ to revert back to the original settings?

Comment: Well I was able to get it working again. I needed to start 'Task Running Explorer' from the View -> Other Windows -> Task Manager. After I did this I was able to see TaskManager, see what gulp was doing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to start 'Task Running Explorer' from the View -> Other Windows -> Task Manager. After I did this I was able to see TaskManager, see what gulp was doing, etc.